# Create IGrouping based on sub List items

Tags: c#

G'day folks.

Lets just say I had the following class:

```cs
    public class ObjectA
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
        public List<string> ListProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

and a collection class like this:

```cs
    public class CollectionB
    {
        public List<ObjectA> Collection { get; set; }
    }
```

which is used thusly:

```cs
    public void MethodC(CollectionB coll)
    {
        coll.Add(new ObjectA 
        {
            PropertyA = "merry"
            ListProperty = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" }
        });
        coll.Add(new ObjectA 
        {
            PropertyA = "xmas"
            ListProperty = new List<string> { "yee", "har", "foo" }
        });
        coll.Add(new ObjectA 
        {
            PropertyA = "folks"
            ListProperty = new List<string> { "bar", "bah", "humbug" }
        });
    }
```

How would one create an `IGrouping<string, ObjectA>` from CollectionB using each of ObjectA's `PropertyList` property strings as keys (`"foo"`, `"bar"` etc)?

Duplicates in the groups don't bother me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these setups I've got a preference for query syntax:

```
from a in coll from p in a.ListProperty group a by p
```

Side note: The above will create an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ObjectA>>` To get a list, simply use `(from a in coll from p in a.ListProperty group a by p).ToList()`

Comment: You know, I feel like a real clown-shoe now.

I  didn't even consider using query syntax, mainly because its been about 8 years since I've even needed to use it.

Now it seems bloody obvious ;)

Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.SelectMany(t => t.ListProperty.Select(q => new { ObjectA = t, Prop = q  })).GroupBy(t => t.Prop, w=>w.ObjectA)
```

Comment: Cheers, but I think @Me.Name 's answer is probably more succinct. I'll definitely write your one down though for future use just in case :)